# Bitmask to flip bits ... without XOR?

Tags: xor, bitmask

Pretty simple, really. I want to negate an integer which is represented in 2's complement, and to do so, I need to first flip all the bits in the byte. I know this is simple with XOR--just use XOR with a bitmask 11111111. But what about without XOR? (i.e. just AND and OR). Oh, and in this crappy assembly language I'm using, NOT doesn't exist. So no dice there, either.

Comment: Even a "crappy assembly language" should have some way of doing NOT. Maybe it's called something else?

Comment: It might help if you listed _all_ of the the operations actually available in this "crappy assembly language".  It is provably impossible to do what you are trying to do with just AND and OR.

Comment: Yeah, I'm dumb. All I had to do was subtract the integer from 0 ... which negates it. Clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't build a NOT gate out of AND and OR gates.

As I was asked to explain, here it is nicely formatted. Let's say you have any number of `AND` and `OR` gates. Your inputs are `A`, 0 and 1. You have six possibilities as you can make three  pairs out of three signals (pick one that's left out) and two gates. Now:

```
Operation  Result
A AND A    A
A AND 1    A
A AND 0    0
A OR A     A
A OR 1     1
A OR 0     A
```

So after you fed any of your signals into the first gate, your new set of signals is still just A, 0 and 1. Therefore any combination of these gates and signals will only get you A, 0 and 1. If your final output is A, then this means that for both values of A it won't equal !A, if your final output is 0 then A = 0 is such a value that your final value is not !A same for 1.

Edit: that monotony comment is also correct! Let me repeat here: if you change any of the inputs of AND / OR from 0 to 1 then the output won't decrease. Therefore if you claim to build a NOT gate then I will change your input from 0 to 1 , your output also can't decrease but it should -- that's a contradiction.

Comment: Do you think you could explain why?

Comment: Why? Well, say you have A, 0, 1 AND, OR... now combine 'em you will immediately see. A AND A is A, A AND 0 is 0, A AND 1 is A, A OR A is A, A OR 1 is 1, A OR 0 is A. You want to combine these signals and gates and get to A but as you can see after the first step you still only have A, 0, 1 signals and it's impossible to break out of this circle.

Comment: Because AND and OR are monotone functions, and the composition of monotone functions is a monotone function, and NOT is not a monotone function.  (A "monotone function" is one which, when you increase one of its inputs, the output stays the same or increases.)

Comment: @Asker is right. The NOT function is a basic operation of boolean logic <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(logic)#Basic_operations>. The operations are defined axiomatically, which means *you just have to believe it*

Comment: NOT is a function defined by its inputs and outputs and you can meticulously inspect the inputs and the outputs. Nothing to believe.

Answer (score 0):

Does `(foo & ~bar) | (~foo & bar)` do the trick?

Edit: Oh, NOT doesn't exist. Didn't see that part!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get NOT either.